# If every continuous function on $F$ can be extended to $\mathbb R$, prove $F$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Suppose $F ⊂ \mathbb R$ is such that every continuous function from $F$ to $\mathbb R$ can be
> extended to a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. Prove that $F$ is a closed subset
> of $\mathbb R$.

Examples of continuous function on open sets which cannot be extended to $\mathbb R$ can be formed easily, but how to prove the statement?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if $a$ is in the closure of $F$ but not in $F$, try $f(x) = 1/(x-a)$.